# NPE while dynamically initialzing TableRows in Android

Tags: android, tablerow

I´m new to Android development and now facing a fatal error. I´d like to create a table with dynamically added TableRows. At the second line of makeNewRow() I get a NullPointerException. In other questions, that were posted here, I read that the ContentView might not be set before initializing the TableRow but my onCreate-method is working properly. When testing that app on my phone, I see the TableLayout, which already contains one row, on my screen before the app crashes.
However I guess that is anything wrong with my "this" but I did not find any help for that so far...

Notice for understanding the code: The AsyncTask JSONDownload returns a JSONArray and calls makeNewRow() in its postExecute()-method. The JSONArray is filled correctly.

```
package com.***;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Tabelle extends Activity {

url= "***";
JSONDownloader jdown;
TableLayout tl;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabelle);
    tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabelleLayout);
    new JSONDownloader().execute(url);
}

public void makeNewRow(JSONArray platzierung, int row) {
    row++;
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setId(100+row);
    tr.setLayoutParams(
            new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
            );

    TextView platz = new TextView(this);
    platz.setId(200+row);
    platz.setText(row);
    platz.setLayoutParams(
            new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    0,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    1f)
            );
    tr.addView(platz);

    /**other textviews **/

    tl.addView(tr);
}
  }
```

The logcat:

```
11-04 17:26:59.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5389): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 17:26:59.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5389): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-04 17:26:59.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5389): at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
11-04 17:26:59.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5389): at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3228)
11-04 17:26:59.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5389): at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:416)
11-04 17:26:59.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5389): at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:168)
11-04 17:26:59.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5389): at android.widget.TableRow.<init>(TableRow.java:61)
11-04 17:26:59.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5389): at com.***.Tabelle.makeNewRow(Tabelle.java:51)
11-04 17:26:59.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5389): at com.***.Tabelle.showTable(Tabelle.java:37)
11-04 17:26:59.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5389): at com.***.JSONDownloader.onPostExecute(JSONDownloader.java:79)
11-04 17:26:59.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5389): at com.***.JSONDownloader.onPostExecute(JSONDownloader.java:1)
11-04 17:26:59.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5389): at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
11-04 17:26:59.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5389): at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
11-04 17:26:59.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5389): at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
11-04 17:26:59.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5389): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-04 17:26:59.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5389): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-04 17:26:59.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5389): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
11-04 17:26:59.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5389): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 17:26:59.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5389): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-04 17:26:59.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5389): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
11-04 17:26:59.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5389): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
11-04 17:26:59.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5389):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Hope someone can help me! :)

Edit: Here is my code for onPostExecute():

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute (JSONArray jarray){
   table=new Tabelle();
   table.showTable(jarray);
}
```

Comment: Please format your logcat correctly and add the code for your onPostExecute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you added your `onPostExecute()` method and the error makes sense now. You are trying to (incorrectly) create a new Activity instead of using the existing one. Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute (JSONArray jarray){
    Tabelle.this.showTable(jarray);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved the problem! Now, after you mentioned it, it was suddenly so clear to me. Sometimes the simpliest things go wrong...